# Get public methods/functions for object

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I've this code:

```
var Helper = function () {

    this.prototype = {
        loadScripts: function (scripts, path) {
            scripts = $.map(scripts, function (scr) {
                return $.getScript((path || '') + scr);
            });

            scripts.push($.Deferred(function (deferred) {
                $(deferred.resolve);
            }));

            return $.when.apply($, scripts);
        }
    };

    return {
        loadScripts: loadScripts,
    };
};
```

But I cannot access the method loadScripts with Helper.loadScripts() like here:

```
// Getting TypeError: FraggyHelper.loadScripts is not a function
Helper.loadScripts(['foo.js', 'bar.js'], '/path/to/');
```

Why is that? And how can I get access to this function?

Comment: Where did you get that `this.prototype` from???

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var Helper = {
    loadScripts: function (scripts, path) {
        scripts = $.map(scripts, function (scr) {
            return $.getScript((path || '') + scr);
        });

        scripts.push($.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
        }));

        return $.when.apply($, scripts);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Helper = (function () {

    var loadScripts =  function (scripts, path) {
        scripts = $.map(scripts, function (scr) {
            return $.getScript((path || '') + scr);
        });

        scripts.push($.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
        }));

        return $.when.apply($, scripts);
    };

return {
    loadScripts: loadScripts,
}  })();
```

You can do IFFE like above

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
var Helper = function () {};

Helper.prototype.loadScripts = function (scripts, path) {
  scripts = $.map(scripts, function (scr) {
    return $.getScript((path || '') + scr);
  });

  scripts.push($.Deferred(function (deferred) {
    $(deferred.resolve);
  }));

  return $.when.apply($, scripts);
};

// Getting TypeError: FraggyHelper.loadScripts is not a function
new Helper().loadScripts(['foo.js', 'bar.js'], '/path/to/');
```